# NVidia GeForce GTX 770 not recognized on a Dell PowerEdge T310 running Ubuntu 16

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, dell

I have a 4 year old Dell PowerEdge T310 server that I want too upgrade with a NVidia GeForce GTX 770 card. The machine is running Ubuntu 16. I inserted the card and also, as a temporary measure, added a 2nd power supply (currently outside the chassis) since the original one does not have enough power and I could not find a generic ATX PS that would be compatible to run the whole machine.

The machine currently boots half-way and then goes into some sort of infinite loop with a message "Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server..." displayed on the screen. Note that the monitor is currently connected to the computer as VGA. If I connect it to the new card it does not display at all.

When I enter BIOS, I can see the card as an external device.

So it seems that it detects the card on boot but not completely, so I can't even reach the stage of installing drivers for the card.

Is this something Ubuntu-specific? How can I diagnose and fix it? Thx

Comment: Prior to installing your new card are you using nouveau driver ?  Was your current graphics card nvidia ?

Comment: @ScottStensland I didn't even have a graphics card before. The original graphics is integrated, and pretty crappy actually (maybe because it's a server). Should I preinstall a nouveau driver before installing the card?

Comment: yes ... and post your findings

Comment: ended up installing the card on a different machine...

Comment: what OS on different machine ?   did you get it running on ubuntu 16 ?

Comment: Technically, it was my friend who did it on his computer, but, yes, on Ubuntu 16